# There is an easy way to add social login on Jhipster microservice Gateway?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-social

When I generate a monolithic app using **yo**, I'm asked if I want to use social login, but this doesn't happen during gateway creation on microservice model.

Is there an easy way of adding social login on microservice gateway, or do I need to make it manually?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible without changing the structure of the generator.

This cannot be a recommended approach but you may force the variable 'enableSocialSignIn' in .yo-rc.json or directly in the prompt.js file of the server repository.

```
function askForServerSideOpts() { 
    ...
        this.enableSocialSignIn = true;
        done();
    }.bind(this));
}
```