# JHipster UAA service and social logins

Tags: java, oauth, jwt, jhipster, spring-social

I have been playing around with the jhipster generators recently, in particular the microservices ones. It seems very straight forward to achieve social login with an apigateway service, but when I opt for OAUTH2 via jhipster UAA I don't seem to get this option.

Is there a way to federate to facebook/google etc via the UAA service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to run both together.
That is why, I have forked JHipster to implement some tricky changes on the generator itself as explained here:
[There is an easy way to add social login on Jhipster microservice Gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127414/there-is-an-easy-way-to-add-social-login-on-jhipster-microservice-gateway/45823567#45823567)